# $(a,b] \times (c,d] = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i] \times (c_i, d_i]$, show that $(b-a)(d-c) = \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)(d_i - c_i)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $(a,b] \times (c,d] = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i] \times (c_i, d_i]$, where $\{(a_i,b_i]\times(c_i,d_i]: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ are disjoint, show that $(b-a)(d-c) = \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)(d_i - c_i)$.

Well this is a necessary proposition when we are defining Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. From the graph it's quite clear that the statement is true. However, I found it hard to prove it analytically. Here is my attempt:

First we enumerate $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\cdots,a_n,b_n$ in an increasing order: $s_1 \leq s_2 \leq \cdots s_{2n}$, where $s_1 = a$, $s_{2n} = b$. Also enumerate $c_i,d_i,1 \leq i \leq n$ in an increasing order: $t_1 \leq t_2 \leq \cdots \leq t_{2n}$. Then we have 
$$
  (b-a)(d-c) = \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{2n-1}(s_{i+1} - s_i)(t_{j+1} - t_j)
$$
That is, $(b-a)(d-c)$ equals to the sum of area of $\{(s_i,s_{i+1}]\times(s_j,s_{j+1}]: 1 \leq i,j \leq 2n-1\}$. On the other hand, for each $k$, $(b_k - a_k)(d_k - c_k)$ equals to the sum of area of the small rectangles in it. Since every small rectangle $(s_i,s_{i+1}]\times(s_j,s_{j+1}]$ is contained in only one $(a_k, b_k]\times (c_k, d_k]$, we have $(b-a)(d-c) = \sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - a_k)(d_k - c_k)$.

I don't like the proof that I came up with...In fact, it does not seem clear analytically that

> every small rectangle $(s_i,s_{i+1}]\times(s_j,s_{j+1}]$ is contained in only one $(a_k, b_k]\times (c_k, d_k]$

So I would like to ask for a concise and clear proof. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you allowed to use? Also what's the point of enumerating the $a$'s and $b$'s like that? You never use $j$ in your sum

Comment: Ah, I correct it. My thought was to partitioning these rectangles so that in the summation, $i$ and $j$ can vary independently. I think there are some problems with my proof still, so I am looking for better proof. Free to use any method except drawing a graph.

Comment: I think you are making this harder than it really is: you have a rectangle which is the disjoint union of smaller rectangles, therefore its area is the sum of the areas of the smaller rectangles

Comment: Yes, it's quite clear geometrically, but I want a proof in purely analytical way.

Comment: What's your proof for the first equality? Also I'm guessing you are assuming the small rectangles are disposed in a certain way, i.e. $a_1 = a$, $b_1 = a_2$, $b_2 = a_3$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can show this by induction on $n$, the base case $n=1$ being trivial. Consider those rectangles that have $d_i=d$. If there is only one, remove this rectangle and apply the induction hypothesis. If there are more, consider $f=\max(\{c_i: d_i=d\})$. Replace each rectangle of the form $(a_i,b_i] \times (c_i,d]$ by two rectangles: $(a_i,b_i] \times (c_i,f]$ and $(a_i,b_i] \times (f,d]$. We can apply the induction hypothesis on $(a,b] \times (c,f]$. 
We are left with the part $(a,b] \times (f,d]$. This part is partitioned in rectangles of the form $(a_i,b_i] \times (f,d]$. Hence we may restrict ourselves to the case $c_i=c$, $d_i=d$ for all $i$, in other words it is enough to show this in one dimension instead of $2$.